# Is it reliable to use RPC over Internet?

Tags: sockets, rpc

Is it reliable to use RPC over Internet ? My boss mentioned ISP's will do filtering if they detect a binary protocol being transferred over wire. I still didn't under stand the reason why ISP should block binary protocols. ISP's purpose is to route the packets as soon as possible.

What are the general opinions in using RPC over Internet ? I can have alternatives to use a well known protocol like HTTP or HTTPS and transfer my content over that. But still what are the issues if I just plainly use a binary protocol in a not-so popular port ?

Comment: Binary, in most cases, is fine. Some ISPs (few) will require everything to be proxyable via HTTP. What RPC protocol? Some simply will not work with NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you answered your own question.  If some ISP's filter binary protocols then it isn't reliable.

As for why ISP's would block the protocol I don't know.

If you're worried about reliability then use HTTP as you have that available.